# Server Monitoring tool

Tags: monitoring

I am looking for a webserver monitoring tool. As of now one of my websites is hosted on Dreamhost Linux VPS, whenever there is an issue like high RAM usage , their standard response is to look in their wiki http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PS_Optimization

Now I am not into servers and stuff and it becomes a real pain to interpret those shell commands.

Is there any easy UI based tool (free or commercial) available which can help me with real time monitoring of my VPS server? (I am on Windows XP)

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into something like [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It's a very simple system monitoring tool that collects data and presents it graphically via a web interface. They have plug-ins for most basic system monitoring (disk, cpu, memory, network, etc), as well as support for many applications (Apache, PostgreSQL, MySQL, sendmail, postfix, ntpd, etc).

The best thing about Munin is that you get a lot of information for almost no work. Installation and setup is a 5 minute job if you do it manually, and a 30 second job if you are using Debian/Ubuntu. The only thing you have to do after dropping it in is add an entry for the host to the config and make sure the plug-ins you want are enabled.

I haven't found anything else that will give you as much information as easily, and with as little effort, as Munin does.  To see it in operation, the Munin guys also have a demo site [here](http://munin.ping.uio.no/).

Comment: Munin is a good thing to try because it's easy to set up.  On the downside, munin doesn't scale very well, but that won't really matter for your small configuration.

Comment: Thanks I "ll try this in sometime and update my progress here.

Answer (score 2):

I use Nagios and Centreon. It's probably the best you can get for free. You will see it can be a big PITA to install and configure. So I found this very cool automated install called Fan. You can check at http://fannagioscd.sourceforge.net/

Basically, it's a autoinstall that takes care of everything for you. It's not quite up to date, but it gets the job done!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The best commercial software for monitoring a Linux host is [**Nagios**](http://www.nagios.com/products/nagiosxi).

But if it is for only one server and you dont want to pay, then you should consider [**ZABBIX**](http://www.zabbix.com/)

Comment: Nagios has several versions. One is open source too: http://www.nagios.org/

Comment: there are enough people on earth that would certainly not agree with the statement that Nagios is the best monitoring solution out there -especially the trending/history part and logging are virtually non existent with Nagios and IMHO monitoring isn't only looking at the current values since they are ouf of context without historic values. From where do you know that 100% CPU usage on a box is actually a reason for concern if you don't know that the average value was 20% over the last 3 months?